# Responsive grid in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

Referring to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264511/back-button-on-first-page-when-navigationpage-used), I need some help making the listview items responsive on all the platform, all the sizes and also on landscape and portrait  mode. The listview which I have now becomes tiny on a 10" screen. I would like to make it responsive. Any reference to achieve this?

Comment: Please remove the last question and post another if you still need help on the background color change, as you should only be asking one question per post.

Comment: @Pete ok I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have some kind of fixed width issue perhaps if your `ListView` is small and not covering the entire page?

On your `mainList` you are setting to the `ContentPage` without any layout options.

Try setting the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of the outer element first, and once you get that working, focus on the inner controls to ensure they take up the desired amount of space afterwards.

```
        o.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        o.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
```

Change the `ListView` `BackgroundColor` to some noticeable color to help you ensuring that things are laying out correctly.

Comment: The listview is covering the entire page. But the issue is with size of the row and font size. As compared to toolbaritems the listview text and the whole height is small

Comment: Can you send over and I will take a quick look?  It most likely still has to do with the HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions on your inner children / List view item somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Every Xamarin.Forms.Element(and therefore every page) implements a Width and a Height property, you can use these to adjust your layout depending on Page-Size.
You should take a loot at this page regarding the VisualElement class https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement/

You could also use Device.Idiom to check if you are on a phone or Tablet and handle each case individually:

```
        if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            //your code goes here
        else
            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            //your code goes here
        else
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
```

For landscape/protrait simply check with the Width/Height-Properties of your page:

```
        if (Width > Height)
        {
            //"landscape"
        }
        else
        {
            //"portrait"
        }
```

For handling Orientation changes implement an Event-Handler for SizeChanged or simply overwrite OnSizeAllocated (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeAllocated/p/System.Double/System.Double/)