# Multi select list view using background change

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

With reference to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264511/back-button-on-first-page-when-navigationpage-used) I would like to know if there is any way by which I can only change the background color of list item instead of using a switch control?

I have used a switch control to indicate multiple selection, but with switch control I get this ON/OFF text on some of the platforms which is unnecessary so I am looking for option to change the background of the list item instead of switch control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `Grid` `BackgroundColor` that is the root of the list item `ViewCell`.

In your code you have:-

```
public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate()
            : base()
        {

            Grid objGrid = new Grid();
            objGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
```

So your already setting the background to Gray.

Create another property for the Background Color in your view model, and hook into the Switch being toggled.  You can then set the view model to the appropriate color you need for a selection / non-selection.

Then create a binding for the `objGrid` above for the `BackgroundColor` property binding to this ViewModel property.

If however, your on about removing the `Switch` control, you will want to do something similar to what is described earlier.   However, instead of hooking into the `Switch` toggled event handler, you will want to create a `TapGestureRecognizer` and bind this to the `Grid`, so you can update the ViewModel as appropriate.

**Update 1**:-

To handle the `Grid` background color being a specific color should an item be selected or not you will need to create a `IValueConverter` that is bound to your `IsSelected` boolean property to determine the appropriate color to display as the background of the `Grid`.

```
public class BackGroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Color.Gray;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

You will then need to create a `Binding` that uses this, as so:-

```
objGrid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundColorProperty, "IsSelected", converter: new BackGroundColorConverter());
```

As a separate thing, to remove the `Switch`, comment the following three lines:-

```
Switch mainSwitch = new Switch();
mainSwitch.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, new Binding("IsSelected"));
objGrid.Children.Add(mainSwitch, 2, 0);
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for removing the switch control use background change for multiselection

Comment: I would also want to get the selected listitems list. So if we remove switch control can I still get the list of items selected?

Comment: Also I have one omre function on tap of the listitem, So there a way by which I can have long tap first for multiselection

Comment: @Arti your ViewModel will contain all the information that you require to detect the multiple selected items.  If you wanted to go with long tapping, there is support that, although it doesn't sound such an intuitive approach if your going down that route.  A simple tap on / off to select and de-select an item should be enough.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it on double tap instead of single tap?

Comment: @Arti You could look into using a `TapGestureRecognizer`.  In that you can specify the number of taps required via, `NumberOfTapsRequired`.

Comment: The background change doesn't work as expected for iOS. sometimes on single tap the row is selected and sometimes on double tap. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change background of list items by adding selectors in drawables and using `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background"` in list view tag of XML.

Example selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_gradient" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />
```

Change values accordingly for different states like state pressed,state enabled etc.